# Typescript. Not compiling at specific machine

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, compilation, tsc

I have small project that is perfectly compiling on my home machine, but I'm getting hundreds of errors on another PC.
The only difference between environment I can notice is that PC that I have troubles on is under windows 8 (PC's on windows 10 and ubuntu works fine with it).

Global npm list (depth=0):

```
+-- npm@4.1.1
+-- typescript@2.1.5
`-- typings@2.1.0
```

`tsc version = 1.0.3.0`

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

The problems starts with `/// <reference path="node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts" />`

That is how my output looks like:
[image: errors]

Comment: On the Windows machine, what is the output of this command: `where tsc`

Comment: @cartant `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.js
C:\Users\Aliaksei.Kaupayeu\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc
C:\Users\Aliaksei.Kaupayeu\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd`

Comment: That first one is an ancient version of `tsc`. You will need to examine your `PATH` and remove `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0` from it. And then close and re-open any command prompts, etc.

Comment: That is my `PATH` variable `C:\Users\Aliaksei.Kaupayeu\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`

Comment: What about the [system `PATH`](http://superuser.com/a/949577/627721)? It must be in there somewhere.

Comment: @cartant You are my hero! It works! I wasn't able to work with some tasks last 3 days because of that. Please write answer, I will accept that. I think it can be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some old versions of Visual Studio install an early version of the TypeScript SDK in the following location:

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0
```

Unfortunately, that SDK directory is added to the system `PATH` and causes problems if it precedes the `%USERPROFILE%\Roaming\npm` directory, as an old version of `tsc` will be run instead of the NPM-installed version.

To determine whether or not this is the problem, run the following command to see the location of `tsc`:

```
where tsc
```

If it's in the SDK's directory, you will need to remove that directory from the system `PATH` (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/949577/627721) for Windows 10 instructions) and then close and re-open any command prompts.